# Finding out what redirects me to a scary URL

Tags: browser, redirection, internet-security

In Internet Explorer 11.0.9600, the website `http://gus-ev.de/` (I don't want to make it a link for security reasons) redirects me to `http://www.freenom.link/de/index.html?lang=de`. It does not happen in Firefox 49.0.2, so it might be browser / user agent specific.

How can I find out how the original site is redirected or redirects me to the scary one?

Can I set a breakpoint in the JavaScript debugger which breaks upon redirection?

I'd like to inform the website owner about it, but first I'd like to understand it myself and make sure to exclude any issues on my side.

Comment: Does it only happen in one kind of browser? If so they might redirect you based on your UserAgent or some malicious software might be interacting with your browser.

Comment: @Seth: yes it might be based on the user agent. I don't have more browsers to test. Ideally I'd like to set a breakpoint in the debugger which breaks on redirection. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I also get redirected in Chrome v53.0. I did get a [scary malware warning](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/isaac79b41e5947ad2bb12fab71e3ba9ff9fe.png), though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to trace all requests and responses going through your browser is to install [OWASP ZAP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project). After setting up a proxy and installing a root certificate (Don't worry, you'll generate this cert by yourself and it'll never leave your computer), you will be able to see the requests and responses for everything you do in your browser.

One thing to look for is response codes like [301](https://httpstatuses.com/301) and [302](https://httpstatuses.com/302), which are common redirection responses. The body of such responses should then contain a location header, telling the browser where to go. You can see from what domain the responses were served.

If you don't find any redirection responses like that, it's probably some javascript doing the redirect. What you could do in that case is find the first request to the infected malicious site, and then work back to find a response that contained javascript that might redirect you.

I'll update this answer later today after I get home from work with some screenshots.

Edit: I also get redirected on Chrome 53.0. I get a [scary warning](https://ducohosting.com/screenshots/isaac79b41e5947ad2bb12fab71e3ba9ff9fe.png) when trying to visit `gus-ev.de`, though. [It looks like Google is aware of an issue](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/?hl=en#url=gus-ev.de).